# Negotiating after disclosing Salary Expected

Tags: job-offer

i am likely to get a job offer with a company for which i am very excited but i did a mistake by disclosing my salary expectation in start itself. After checking the current market trend and another job offer which i have, i feel that i asked for less initially whereas at my experience i can get a better salary. Also the company would easily be having a bigger salary range for that job profile. Please suggest how can i talk to HR for a higher salary and on what points should i negotiate.

Comment: If you said what you're willing to work for, they're unlikely to go much, if at all, over that. The environment is _always_ changing, though, so chading after the best possible offer can mean never actually accepting a job; at some point you have to be willing to say "good enough". Unless you're something special, you need ghem more than they need you...

Comment: "disclosing my salary expectation" - in what form or manner did you do this? Also, although you have a basis for expecting more, do you have a basis for needing more? And when did you make the disclosure - before the other job offer or after? And has your current company made any attempts to keep you with additional compensation? You've left a lot to our imaginations...

Comment: Voting to close as off topic - "Questions should get answers explaining why and how to make a decision, not advice on what to do"

Answer (score 4):

You don't have job offer so right now so you don't have a salary to negotiate.

When you get an offer it will either be acceptable or not. If not make a counter.

You are not really in a position to argue your worth in the market.  They know what they pay their people.  They know the market. Don't lecture them on the market.

If they are low balling you they may accept your counter.

A good company will have a pretty tight pay range.  If you perform and move up and then your pay increases.  If you like the company and the offer exceeds or meets your initial expectation then just consider going with it.

Comment: Negotiations begin *far* before offers are formally extended.

Comment: @djechlin No kidding, "mistake by disclosing my salary expectation"

Answer (score 2):

Asking for a higher salary after the job offer, could easily get your job offer taken back. Because usually several people are involved in the calculations and you already gave them a rough price. Unless you have some special skills then you're easily replaceable.

However you don't need to accept a job offer, you can negotiate when you have one, saying you'd love to work for them, but not for the same pay you were getting elsewhere, explain the market rate etc,. and see which way it goes. There is still leeway for negotiation.

Comment: Asking for a higher salary before getting the job offer could lead to not getting an offer, yet we still do it.

Comment: yes, that's why I left it out, because in my experience it's an automatic disqualification from giving them a job offer at all. It looks like they're either overly mercenary, or badly prepared, neither of which are desirable traits all else being equal.

Answer (score 2):

As always in a negotiation, it helps if you have arguments backing your demands.
If you have another job offer, you can safely try raising your salary.

Explain them:

- The initial position (or how you understood it) is different from what you now know it actually is: after talking with them, you learned new information about the job and want to be paid accordingly.
- Salary is just 1 item in a benefits package: if they have a lot of other benefits (pension funds, paid vacation days, company car, insurance, phone, laptop, ...), the salary can be lower, if they don't, the salary will be higher. It's the total package that counts.
- You have another job offer in the range of XXX-YYY, which corresponds with what you believe you are worth.
- You did your research on the job market (glassdoor.com, other collegues in the domain) and know the salary ranges are XXX-YYY.

If they challenge you that you asked for less before, remain calm, polite and friendly, but explain that you are convinced you are worth the salary you are asking for, and that you can deliver a lot of value to their company - and believe you should be compensated accordingly.